# JavaFX 2.0 with web based MySQL Database?

Tags: mysql, web-applications, javafx-2

any ideas on how could i make desktop application (build on top of JavaFX 2.0) that will connect to a web-based MySQL database?

Any ideas, reference, insights would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is a web-based MySQL database?

Answer (score 0):

I have done this before some time ago also using JavaFx. First you will need to download the MySQL/J Java Connector from [Here](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/) then you could follow [this blog post](http://mxshrestha.wordpress.com/2011/03/09/mysql-javafx/) for how to use it and set it up to use inside of your JavaFx application.